# How does delayed durability impact a database which is part of synchronous availability group?

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, sql-server-2019

Delayed durability (forced) setting on a database ensures that client application gets the commit without waiting for the log to be flushed (written) to disk.

Synchronous AG requires that the transaction is written to the primary log (flush to disk), and to the secondary log (flush to disk), only then will the client receive commit.

For a database participating in an AG will this setting (delayed durability = forced) apply to both primary and secondary database, and on both the servers SQL engine will not wait for the log to be written to disk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's documented.

> **Always On Availability Groups and Mirroring**
>
> Delayed durable transactions do not guarantee any durability on either the primary or
> any of the secondaries. In addition, they do not guarantee any
> knowledge about the transaction at the secondary. After commit,
> control is returned to the client before any acknowledgment is
> received from any synchronous secondary. Replication to secondary
> replicas does continue to happen as flush to disk on the primary
> happens.

[Control Transaction Durability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/logs/control-transaction-durability?view=sql-server-ver16)